# How to inject service inside supplier. Repository is null

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I created a factory pattern using supplier. That's ok and it worked fine. The path of the right service is OK, but inside the service that will calculate, the repositories are null. It seems is not being autowired.

I tried to autowire and annotate the classes with @Service and @Component and still not work.

```
@Service
public class Service {

    public responseDTO calculate(Contract contract, Request request) {

        Supplier<TypeFactory> type = TypeFactory::new;

        //HOW TO AUTOWIRE THIS?
        return type.get().getCalculationMethod(contract.getId()).calculate(request);

    }

}
```

```
@Service
public class TypeFactory {

    final static Map<Integer, Supplier<Calculator>> calculationTypeMap = new HashMap<>();

    static {
        calculationTypeMap.put(1, ContractOneType::new);
        calculationTypeMap.put(2, ContractTwoType::new);
    }

    public Calculator getCalculationMethod(Integer type) {
        Supplier<Calculator> method = calculationTypeMap.get(type);
        if (method != null) {
            return method.get();
        }
        throw new IllegalStateException("Type not found");
    }

}
```

```
@Service
public interface Calculator {

    ResponseDTO calculate(Request Request);

}
```

```
@Service
public class ContractOneType implements Calculator {

    @Autowired
    private ContractRepository contractRepository;

    public ResponseDTO calculate(Request request) {

        ResponseDTO responseDTO = new ResponseDTO();

        Contract contract = contractRepository.findById(request.getId()).orElseThrow(() -> new NotFoundException("id not found"));

        //some calculations here with the contract

        return responseDTO;

    }

}
```

The contractRepository is null, is not being autowired. It must be.

Error messages from my code:

> 2019-07-08 10:19:33.078 ERROR
>   [-,21fa294c89e1e207,21fa294c89e1e207,false] 19477 ---
>   [nio-8080-exec-1] c.l.d.t.s.h.GeneralExceptionHandler      :
>   msg="Exception", stacktrace="java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: did you annotate your repository class with @Repository?

Comment: Not sure but may be Spring Java Configurations could help you. Google about `@Configuration` and `@Bean`

Comment: How did you define ContractRepository class ?

Comment: Yes, my repository is with @Repository annotation

Comment: I found a solution, I am goingo to post soon.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution changing my supplier that is creating new instances, I just create instances for my implementations and set @Autowired for them.

And that's why my repository is not being @Autowired.

Here's my code:

```
@Service
public class TypeFactory {

    final static Map<Integer, Supplier<Calculator>> calculationTypeMap = new HashMap<>();

    @Autowired
    ContractOneType contractOneType;

    @Autowired
    ContractTwoType contractTwoType;

    static {
        calculationTypeMap.put(1, contractOneType);
        calculationTypeMap.put(2, contractTwoType);
    }

    public Calculator getCalculationMethod(Integer type) {
        Supplier<Calculator> method = calculationTypeMap.get(type);
        if (method != null) {
            return method.get();
        }
        throw new IllegalStateException("Type not found");
    }

}
```

```
@Component
public class ContractOneType implements Calculator {

    @Autowired
    private ContractRepository contractRepository;

    public ResponseDTO calculate(Request request) {

        ResponseDTO responseDTO = new ResponseDTO();

        Contract contract = contractRepository.findById(request.getId()).orElseThrow(() -> new NotFoundException("id not found"));

        //some calculations here with the contract

        return responseDTO;

    }

}
```

```
public interface Calculator {
    ResponseDTO calculate(Request Request);

}
```